# Can I prevent SQL 2008 Server Management Studio's intellisense from autocompleting with the longest word?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL 2008 Server Management Studio: is there a way to keep intellisense from always picking the longest word to autocomplete?  For example, I could be trying to type the word `client` and it'll autocomplete with `clientdetails`.

Comment: Which version of SSMS? I'm using 10.50.1600.1 and do not have mentioned problem.

Comment: @Sandy I'm on version 10.0.4000.0.  That might be part of the problem. :) I'll look for SP updates and see if that helps.

Comment: @Sandy Actually, this http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8fbfc1de-d25e-4790-88b5-7dda1f1d4e17&displaylang=en says 10.0.4 is SP2? Am I missing something?

Comment: I thought that, 10.5 is 2008R2, 10.0 is 2008. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: I'm on 10.50.2500.0 and have the same issue. Very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to just disable IntelliSense, the more I use it, the less I like it. Although before I tried it, I loved it :)

Just better to learn to hand-code things correctly. Mostly IntelliSense intefere's with that

Comment: au-contraire. Autosense helps me type even faster than my normal 50-60 WPM, with autocompletion and learning how to use it. I agree that while it's still building it's database it takes time for it to catch up, especially on larger projects, but on small stuff it makes things blazingly simple.